# Same query on different postgres database (with same data) takes 700x longer

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-execution-plan

I've been trying to diagnose an issue for the past few weeks.  Our production database is taking a very long time (84sec) to run queries that run very quickly on our QA DB (120ms).

- Production DB is far more powerful than our QA DB
- Prod Postgres Version: `PostgreSQL 9.3.16 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit`
- QA DB Postgres Version: `PostgreSQL 9.6.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit`
- QA DB is backed up with most recent data.  There is some scrubbing of sensitive information in the backup process
- Running an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` shows that the query plans for the two dbs are VASTLY different, but I'm having trouble understanding the difference

Anything you can do to point me in the right direction I would really appreciate.
Thank you

Production query plan:

```
 Limit  (cost=5411.63..5411.63 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=84719.786..84719.788 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=109988
   ->  Sort  (cost=5411.63..5411.63 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=84719.785..84719.787 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: events.updated_at
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=109988
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5371.22..5411.63 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=273.194..84652.985 rows=25846 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (events.id = filters_2.target_id)
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 134062366
               Filter: ((filters_2.target_id IS NULL) OR (filters_1.target_id IS NOT NULL))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 60
               Buffers: shared hit=109988
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2468.49..2481.16 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=119.443..15665.354 rows=25906 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (events.id = filters_1.target_id)
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 29713058
                     Buffers: shared hit=108373
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1241.39..1253.61 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=94.514..692.546 rows=25906 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=107956
                           ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=1241.31..1241.34 rows=3 width=47) (actual time=94.497..151.266 rows=26171 loops=1)
                                 Merge Cond: (events.id = filters.target_id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2439
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=14.16..14.17 rows=3 width=47) (actual time=64.147..84.460 rows=26171 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: events.id
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3131kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=2022
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=4.18..14.16 rows=3 width=47) (actual time=3.687..46.416 rows=26171 loops=1)
                                             Recheck Cond: (((brand_id = 218) AND (brand_id = 218)) OR ((brand_id IS NULL) AND (brand_id = 218)))
                                             Filter: ((eventable_type)::text = ANY ('{Achievement,Blog,Kudo,Story,User}'::text[]))
                                             Buffers: shared hit=2022
                                             ->  BitmapOr  (cost=4.18..4.18 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=3.369..3.369 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=96
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_events_on_brand_id  (cost=0.00..2.10 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=3.366..3.366 rows=26171 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: ((brand_id = 218) AND (brand_id = 218))
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=96
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_events_on_brand_id  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: ((brand_id IS NULL) AND (brand_id = 218))
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=1227.15..1227.16 rows=19 width=4) (actual time=30.345..30.345 rows=0 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: filters.target_id
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=417
                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1226.95..1227.01 rows=19 width=4) (actual time=30.336..30.336 rows=0 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=417
                                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filters  (cost=381.47..1226.89 rows=127 width=4) (actual time=30.334..30.334 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Recheck Cond: (((constraint_id = 218) OR ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148)) OR ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)) AND ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text))
                                                   Filter: ((NOT visible) AND ((((constraint_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) AND (constraint_id = 218)) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Team'::text) AND ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148))) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text) AND (constraint_id IS NULL))))
                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 1147
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=417
                                                   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=381.47..381.47 rows=634 width=0) (actual time=5.591..5.591 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=149
                                                         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=32.60..32.60 rows=2733 width=0) (actual time=0.464..0.464 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=24
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.16 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: (constraint_id = 218)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=28.29..28.29 rows=2680 width=0) (actual time=0.384..0.384 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=18
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.16 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5229)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.16 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5183)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..23.95 rows=2575 width=0) (actual time=0.373..0.373 rows=2979 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5148)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=12
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_type  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_target_type  (cost=0.00..348.81 rows=35153 width=0) (actual time=5.088..5.088 rows=35092 loops=1)
                                                               Index Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=125
                           ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=1 loops=26171)
                                 Index Cond: (id = events.user_id)
                                 Filter: ((active AND visible) OR ((events.eventable_type)::text = 'Blog'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                 Buffers: shared hit=105517
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1227.10..1227.24 rows=47 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.309 rows=1147 loops=25906)
                           Buffers: shared hit=417
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filters filters_1  (cost=381.53..1226.94 rows=311 width=4) (actual time=5.647..6.835 rows=1147 loops=1)
                                 Recheck Cond: (((constraint_id = 218) OR ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148)) OR ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)) AND ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text))
                                 Filter: (visible AND ((((constraint_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) AND (constraint_id = 218)) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Team'::text) AND ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148))) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text) AND (constraint_id IS NULL))))
                                 Buffers: shared hit=417
                                 ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=381.53..381.53 rows=634 width=0) (actual time=5.595..5.595 rows=0 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=149
                                       ->  BitmapOr  (cost=32.65..32.65 rows=2733 width=0) (actual time=0.449..0.449 rows=0 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=24
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.16 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: (constraint_id = 218)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=3
                                             ->  BitmapOr  (cost=28.32..28.32 rows=2680 width=0) (actual time=0.378..0.378 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=18
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.16 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5229)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.16 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5183)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..23.95 rows=2575 width=0) (actual time=0.366..0.366 rows=2979 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5148)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=12
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_type  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=3
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_target_type  (cost=0.00..348.81 rows=35153 width=0) (actual time=5.110..5.110 rows=35092 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=125
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2902.73..2911.49 rows=2920 width=4) (actual time=0.006..1.438 rows=5175 loops=25906)
                     Buffers: shared hit=1615
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filters filters_2  (cost=349.80..2892.87 rows=19720 width=4) (actual time=19.215..124.613 rows=34923 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                           Filter: (visible AND ((((constraint_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) AND (constraint_id <> 218)) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Team'::text) AND ((constraint_id <> 5229) OR (constraint_id <> 5183) OR (constraint_id <> 5148))) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text) AND (constraint_id IS NOT NULL))))
                           Buffers: shared hit=1615
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_target_type  (cost=0.00..348.81 rows=35153 width=0) (actual time=18.952..18.952 rows=35092 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=125
 Total runtime: 84720.000 ms
(116 rows)
```

QA Query Plan:

```
 Limit  (cost=5474.52..5474.52 rows=10 width=47) (actual time=117.227..117.229 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=97438
   ->  Sort  (cost=5474.52..5474.56 rows=97 width=47) (actual time=117.227..117.227 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: events.updated_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=97438
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=4013.62..5474.10 rows=97 width=47) (actual time=29.635..110.750 rows=23404 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (events.id = filters_2.target_id)
               Filter: ((filters_2.target_id IS NULL) OR (filters_1.target_id IS NOT NULL))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 60
               Buffers: shared hit=97438
               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2023.52..3483.92 rows=97 width=51) (actual time=8.641..83.892 rows=23464 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (events.id = filters_1.target_id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=96393
                     ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=1012.67..2472.99 rows=97 width=47) (actual time=4.906..75.057 rows=23464 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (events.id = filters.target_id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=96119
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.00..1464.98 rows=97 width=47) (actual time=1.750..66.678 rows=23464 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=95845
                                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=4.92..667.30 rows=214 width=47) (actual time=1.738..9.563 rows=23720 loops=1)
                                       Recheck Cond: (((brand_id = 218) AND (brand_id = 218)) OR ((brand_id IS NULL) AND (brand_id = 218)))
                                       Filter: ((eventable_type)::text = ANY ('{Achievement,Blog,Kudo,Story,User}'::text[]))
                                       Heap Blocks: exact=801
                                       Buffers: shared hit=869
                                       ->  BitmapOr  (cost=4.92..4.92 rows=361 width=0) (actual time=1.630..1.630 rows=0 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=68
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_events_on_brand_id  (cost=0.00..2.81 rows=361 width=0) (actual time=1.629..1.629 rows=23720 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: ((brand_id = 218) AND (brand_id = 218))
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=68
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_events_on_brand_id  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: ((brand_id IS NULL) AND (brand_id = 218))
                                 ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.08..3.72 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=23720)
                                       Index Cond: (id = events.user_id)
                                       Filter: ((active AND visible) OR ((events.eventable_type)::text = 'Blog'::text))
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                       Buffers: shared hit=94976
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1007.22..1007.22 rows=128 width=4) (actual time=3.145..3.145 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=274
                                 ->  Unique  (cost=1006.71..1006.84 rows=128 width=4) (actual time=3.145..3.145 rows=0 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=274
                                       ->  Sort  (cost=1006.71..1006.77 rows=128 width=4) (actual time=3.145..3.145 rows=0 loops=1)
                                             Sort Key: filters.target_id
                                             Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                             Buffers: shared hit=274
                                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filters  (cost=283.82..1005.81 rows=128 width=4) (actual time=3.137..3.137 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Recheck Cond: (((constraint_id = 218) OR ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148)) OR ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)) AND ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text))
                                                   Filter: ((NOT visible) AND ((((constraint_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) AND (constraint_id = 218)) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Team'::text) AND ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148))) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text) AND (constraint_id IS NULL))))
                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 974
                                                   Heap Blocks: exact=156
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=274
                                                   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=283.82..283.82 rows=641 width=0) (actual time=2.809..2.809 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=118
                                                         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=28.65..28.65 rows=2762 width=0) (actual time=0.237..0.237 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=22
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.17 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: (constraint_id = 218)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=24.33..24.33 rows=2707 width=0) (actual time=0.189..0.189 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=16
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.17 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5229)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.17 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5183)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..19.98 rows=2596 width=0) (actual time=0.183..0.183 rows=2502 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5148)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=10
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_type  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_target_type  (cost=0.00..255.12 rows=34021 width=0) (actual time=2.555..2.555 rows=33832 loops=1)
                                                               Index Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=96
                     ->  Hash  (cost=1009.75..1009.75 rows=314 width=4) (actual time=3.727..3.727 rows=974 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 43kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=274
                           ->  Unique  (cost=1008.49..1008.81 rows=314 width=4) (actual time=3.383..3.596 rows=974 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=274
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=1008.49..1008.65 rows=316 width=4) (actual time=3.381..3.453 rows=974 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: filters_1.target_id
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 70kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=274
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filters filters_1  (cost=283.88..1005.87 rows=316 width=4) (actual time=2.765..3.224 rows=974 loops=1)
                                             Recheck Cond: (((constraint_id = 218) OR ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148)) OR ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)) AND ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text))
                                             Filter: (visible AND ((((constraint_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) AND (constraint_id = 218)) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Team'::text) AND ((constraint_id = 5229) OR (constraint_id = 5183) OR (constraint_id = 5148))) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text) AND (constraint_id IS NULL))))
                                             Heap Blocks: exact=156
                                             Buffers: shared hit=274
                                             ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=283.88..283.88 rows=641 width=0) (actual time=2.744..2.744 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=118
                                                   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=28.70..28.70 rows=2762 width=0) (actual time=0.202..0.202 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=22
                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.17 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                               Index Cond: (constraint_id = 218)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=24.36..24.36 rows=2707 width=0) (actual time=0.169..0.169 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=16
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.17 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5229)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..2.17 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5183)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_id  (cost=0.00..19.98 rows=2596 width=0) (actual time=0.165..0.165 rows=2502 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: (constraint_id = 5148)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=10
                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_constraint_type  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                               Index Cond: ((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_target_type  (cost=0.00..255.12 rows=34021 width=0) (actual time=2.525..2.525 rows=33832 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=96
               ->  Hash  (cost=1943.94..1943.94 rows=13189 width=4) (actual time=20.931..20.931 rows=4918 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 301kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=1045
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1864.80..1904.37 rows=13189 width=4) (actual time=19.485..20.163 rows=4918 loops=1)
                           Group Key: filters_2.target_id
                           Buffers: shared hit=1045
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filters filters_2  (cost=256.07..1855.22 rows=19167 width=4) (actual time=2.605..13.438 rows=33832 loops=1)
                                 Recheck Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                 Filter: (visible AND ((((constraint_type)::text = 'Brand'::text) AND (constraint_id <> 218)) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Team'::text) AND ((constraint_id <> 5229) OR (constraint_id <> 5183) OR (constraint_id <> 5148))) OR (((constraint_type)::text = 'Country'::text) AND (constraint_id IS NOT NULL))))
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=949
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1045
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_filters_on_target_type  (cost=0.00..255.12 rows=34021 width=0) (actual time=2.482..2.482 rows=33832 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((target_type)::text = 'Event'::text)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=96
 Planning time: 1.244 ms
 Execution time: 117.581 ms
(129 rows)
```

Comment: statistics age, effective_cache, all not default settings on both machines are very welcome

Comment: Also a comparison of the size on disk for the relevant table(s) would be great. Do you sometimes VACUUM your production db? btw, I doubt that using a much newer version of PostgreSQL for QA than for production is a good idea.

Comment: vacuum analyze?

Comment: What happens when you use the same Postgres version in QA? (which you should be doing anyway). The (more efficient) choice of a hash join over a nested loop could very well be caused by the improvements to the query optimizer in the 3 years that lie between those two versions.

Comment: Just a quick glance at the two plans show the production database having a much larger data set to trundle through.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: `VACUUM ANALYZE` was the solution

Sorry for delayed response.  We happened to be migrating our DB to another instance type which fixed the issue.  I went back to the original and experimented with the solutions suggested here.  The answer was `vacuum analyze`.  Apparently Heroku autovacuums, but doesn't run the analyze.

One unsolved mystery though, migrating our DB cut the size in half (12GB => 6GB - row counts were the same)